# Call method in controller from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

HTML :

```
<div id="idOfDiv" ng-show="ngShowName">
    Hello
</div>
```

I would like to call the function which is declared in my controller from my directive.
How can I do this? I don't receive an error when I call the function but nothing appears.

This is my directive and controller :

```
var d3DemoApp = angular.module('d3DemoApp', []);

d3DemoApp.controller('mainController', function AppCtrl ($scope,$http, dataService,userService,meanService,multipartForm) {
    $scope.testFunc = function(){
        $scope.ngShowName = true;
    }
});

d3DemoApp.directive('directiveName', [function($scope) {

        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                testFunc : '&'
            },

            link: function(scope) {

                    node.on("click", click);
                    function click(d) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.testFunc();
                        });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: You should use `service`, `factory` would be better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really be using controllers and directives. Angularjs is meant to be used as more of a component(directive) based structure and controllers are more page centric. However if you are going to be doing it this way, there are two ways you can go about it.

First Accessing $parent:

If your directive is inside the controllers scope you can access it using `scope.$parent.mainController.testFunc();`

Second (Preferred Way):

Create a service factory and store your function in there.

```
    d3DemoApp.factory('clickFactory', [..., function(...) {
        var service = {}

        service.testFunc = function(...) {
            //do something
        }

        return service;
    }]);

   d3DemoApp.directive('directiveName', ['clickFactory', function(clickFactory) {

        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            transclude: true,

            link: function(scope, elem) {

                    elem.on("click", click);
                    function click(d) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            clickFactory.testFunc();
                        });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Just a tip, any time you are using a directive you don't need to add $scope to the top of it. `scope` and `scope.$parent` is all you really need, you will always have the scope context. Also if you declare `scope :{}` in your directive you isolate the scope from the rest of the scope, which is fine but if your just starting out could make things quite a bit more difficult for you.

Comment: `node` still doesn't refer to anything in the linking function

Comment: @pulse0ne Correct I overlooked that and I will edit my post.

Comment: If someone could explain the down vote that would be great because my answer is correct and thorough.

Answer (score 0):

In your link function you are using `node`, which doesn't exist. Instead you must use `element` which is the second parameter to link.

```
link: function(scope, element) {

  element.on("click", click);

  function click(d) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      scope.testFunc();
    });
  }
```

Comment: You are still missing a major piece. In your example you still have not addressed the fact that testfunc is tied to nothing.